# How To Check View Contains Another View?

Tags: android, view

Is there a way to check if a view contains another certain view? 
(indexOfChild only works with one level of hierarchy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `findViewById()` to find the view.
like:

```
yourview.findViewById(R.id.childView);
```

Answer (score 27):

If child doesn't have an id, try something like this:

```
child.getParent() == parent
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to check if a View is present inside a ViewGroup? The easiest way I can think of is to use .findViewById() on the ViewGroup, and assign an ID for the View that you're looking for.